# In android, Error during upload file at FTP server

Tags: java, android, ftp, ftp-client

I am building simple app which is upload a file at FTP server.
 - I am using ftp4j-1.6.jar in Reference library.

- [ref](http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98&aaid=120)

code:

FTPDemo-> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.kpbird.ftpdemo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.androidexample.ftpdemo.FtpUpload"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  </application>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
 <TextView  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:text="@string/hello"
  />
  <Button  android:text="Upload"android:id="@+id/button1"                                                                    
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >                                                                
   </Button>
 </LinearLayout>
```

FTPDemo.java

```
package com.androidexample.ftpdemo;

import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPDataTransferListener;
import java.io.File;
import com.kpbird.ftpdemo.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FtpUpload extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

/*********  work only for Dedicated IP ***********/
static final String FTP_HOST= "lumium.com";

/*********  FTP USERNAME ***********/
static final String FTP_USER = "xxxxx";

/*********  FTP PASSWORD ***********/
static final String FTP_PASS  ="xxxxx";

Button btn;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    /********** Pick file from sdcard *******/
    File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/phoneData.txt");

    // Upload sdcard file
    uploadFile(f);

}

public void uploadFile(File fileName){


     FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try {

        client.connect(FTP_HOST,21);// here i get error: java.
        client.login(FTP_USER,FTP_PASS);
        client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
        client.changeDirectory("/upload/");

        client.upload(fileName, new MyTransferListener());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            client.disconnect(true);    
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

/*******  Used to file upload and show progress  **********/

public class MyTransferListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {
    public void started() {         
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Transfer started
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Upload Started ...",            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //System.out.println(" Upload Started ...");
    }

    public void transferred(int length) {
        // Yet other length bytes has been transferred since the last time this
        // method was called
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " transferred ..." + length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //System.out.println(" transferred ..." + length);
    }

    public void completed() {

        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Transfer completed

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " completed ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //System.out.println(" completed ..." );
    }

    public void aborted() {

        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Transfer aborted
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," transfer aborted , please try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //System.out.println(" aborted ..." );
    }

    public void failed() {

        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Transfer failed
        System.out.println(" failed ..." );
    }

}
}
```

LogCat:

```
enter code here

04-06 13:35:28.625: W/System.err(1252): java.net.UnknownHostException: lumium.com
04-06 13:35:28.685: W/System.err(1252): at
java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506) 
04-06 13:35:28.755: W/System.err(1252):     at  
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
04-06 13:35:28.795: W/System.err(1252):     at    
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
04-06 13:35:28.839: W/System.err(1252):     at 
java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:130)
04-06 13:35:28.885: W/System.err(1252):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:209)
04-06 13:35:28.954: W/System.err(1252):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:176)
04-06 13:35:28.994: W/System.err(1252):     at     

it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.connectors.DirectConnector.connectForCommunicationChannel
(DirectConnector.java:37)

04-06 13:35:29.015: W/System.err(1252):     at 
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.connect(FTPClient.java:1031)
04-06 13:35:29.065: W/System.err(1252):     at     
com.androidexample.ftpdemo.FtpUpload.uploadFile(FtpUpload.java:56)
04-06 13:35:29.127: W/System.err(1252):     at  
com.androidexample.ftpdemo.FtpUpload.onClick(FtpUpload.java:45)
04-06 13:35:29.175: W/System.err(1252):     at   
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-06 13:35:29.225: W/System.err(1252):     at  
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-06 13:35:29.285: W/System.err(1252):     at    
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-06 13:35:29.337: W/System.err(1252):     at   
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 13:35:29.404: W/System.err(1252):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-06 13:35:29.475: W/System.err(1252):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-06 13:35:29.515: W/System.err(1252):     at  
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 13:35:29.555: W/System.err(1252):     at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-06 13:35:29.624: W/System.err(1252):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
04-06 13:35:29.665: W/System.err(1252):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-06 13:35:29.694: W/System.err(1252):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
Method)
04-06 13:35:44.795: W/System.err(1252): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client not 
connected
04-06 13:35:44.866: W/System.err(1252):     at 
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.disconnect(FTPClient.java:1107)
04-06 13:35:44.894: W/System.err(1252):     at 
com.androidexample.ftpdemo.FtpUpload.uploadFile(FtpUpload.java:66)
04-06 13:35:44.904: W/System.err(1252):     at   
com.androidexample.ftpdemo.FtpUpload.onClick(FtpUpload.java:45)
04-06 13:35:44.925: W/System.err(1252):     at 
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-06 13:35:44.945: W/System.err(1252):     at  
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-06 13:35:44.965: W/System.err(1252):     at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-06 13:35:45.005: W/System.err(1252):     at  
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 13:35:45.036: W/System.err(1252):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-06 13:35:45.064: W/System.err(1252):     at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-06 13:35:45.095: W/System.err(1252):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 13:35:45.125: W/System.err(1252):     at  
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-06 13:35:45.155: W/System.err(1252):     at 
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-06 13:35:45.187: W/System.err(1252):     at 
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-06 13:35:45.206: W/System.err(1252):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
  Method)
04-06 13:39:17.745: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
  Address family not supported by protocol
04-06 13:43:00.015: I/dalvikvm(75): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048
04-06 13:44:00.114: I/dalvikvm(156): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
04-06 13:44:17.774: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
 Address family not supported by protocol
04-06 13:49:17.809: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException:     
   Address family not supported by protocol
04-06 13:54:17.829: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
   Address family not supported by protocol
04-06 13:59:17.859: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
   Address family not supported by protocol
04-06 14:04:16.786: W/ProcessStats(75): Skipping unknown process pid 3352
04-06 14:04:16.786: W/ProcessStats(75): Skipping unknown process pid 3353
04-06 14:04:17.865: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
 Address family not supported by protocol
04-06 14:09:17.949: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException:  
 Address family not supported by protocol
04-06 14:14:17.974: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException:   
Address family not supported by protocol
04-06 14:14:55.121: D/dalvikvm(156): GC_CONCURRENT freed 301K, 52% free 2790K/5767K,  
 external 2158K/2674K, paused 124ms+215ms
04-06 14:19:17.995: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException:    
Address family not supported by protocol
04-06 14:22:05.270: W/ProcessStats(75): Skipping unknown process pid 4569
04-06 14:24:18.055: D/SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
Address family not supported by protocol
```

what should i do?
any suggestion, link
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Um, from your own reference link, it says **2. Must be required a Server Dedicated IP for FTP File upload**  Did you miss that?

Comment: No, the IP for lumium.com is 74.220.215.93 -- should that ever change, then you'd have to adjust accordingly.

Comment: ok so what should i do? from where i get Server Dedicated IP for FTP file upload..  my project manager give me host: lumium.com , FTP_USER, FTP_PASS... nothing else. is it require any more...

Comment: i got it, by mistakly i does not creat dir in FTP that's why..! Thanx Jeremy Miller for comment.

Answer (score 1):

please see below example
I think it is OnUI problem so I made below code.
I hope this helpfull to anyone
let me know your result 
Thanks for your time.

```
public class MyTransferListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {
    public void started() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Transfer started
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Upload Started ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // System.out.println(" Upload Started ...");
    }
    public void transferred(final int length) {
        // Yet other length bytes has been transferred since the last time
        // this
        // method was called
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " transferred ..." + length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // System.out.println(" transferred ..." + length);
    }
    public void completed() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Transfer completed

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " completed ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // System.out.println(" completed ..." );
    }

    public void aborted() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Transfer aborted
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " transfer aborted , please try again...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // System.out.println(" aborted ..." );
    }
    public void failed() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Transfer failed
                System.out.println(" failed ...");
            }
        });
    }
}
```